# In Cocoa/Cocoa-Touch who manages the size of a view?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a parent view controller that wants to present a child view controller modally. I expect this child view to take up the whole screen. The child view consists of a single table view, which I am creating programmatically in my child view controller. However, the initializer for `UITableView` expects to be given a `CGRect` of its bounds. Presumably (since its the only child) it should be the full available size.

My question is does the view controller itself also have its own size property, in that it is also acting to some extent as an implicit view, or do I somehow need to pass the size to the initializer of my view controller? That doesn't seem right.

I think one thing that is confusing me is that in Cocoa-touch I am presenting a view *controller*, as opposed to a view.

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question: It appears that all view controllers do act as an implicit view in that they have a single `view` property that represents the physical view the controller represents. Therefore, it does have its own size, and I can pass `self.view.bounds` to the table view initializer.